# How to disable C++11 in qmake?

Tags: qt, c++11, qmake

Project file:

```
CONFIG -= qt
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++98
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -std=gnu++11
CONFIG -= c++11
```

Result:

```
g++ -c -pipe -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-reorder -Wno-missing-field-initializers -std=c++98 -DDEBUG -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../../qqq -I. -I../src/jsoncpp -I../lib -I../../../../Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o ../build/debug/obj/TaskManager.o ../src/TaskManager.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-reorder -Wno-missing-field-initializers -std=c++98 -DDEBUG -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../../qqq -I. -I../src/jsoncpp -I../lib -I../../../../Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o ../build/debug/obj/Utils.o ../src/Utils.cpp
```

As you see option `-std=gnu++11` still exist (no any reactoion to `"QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -="`/`"CONFIG -="`).

Qt:

```
Qt Creator 4.3.1
Based on Qt 5.9.1 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)
Built on Jun 29 2017 04:10:39
```

Thank you a lot.

---

P.S. I have compatibility troubles with **gnu++11** (c++ with gcc extenstions) on clean system

```
./qqq: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./qqq)
./qqq: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./qqq)
./qqq: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

and want to use **c++11** (c++ without gcc extenstions) instead **gnu++11** without any extenstions but I cannot to disable it :-(

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to disable C++11 altogether (and switch to C++98) or if you want to just disable GNU extensions and use "plain" C++11. In the latter case, it's just `CONFIG += strict_c++`.

Comment: Are you forcing qmake to run after changing the .pro file? I've seen cases where changes to .pro files are not picked up and qmake is not re-run, so old options are still in effect.

Comment: @peppe A lot of thanks.  gnu++11 is really disappeared. This is what I want. But I'm worried that Qt projects has these troubles with configuring since I uses Qt Creator only as IDE without any Qt features: as text editor and debugger. Since this is most comfortable IDE (e.g. compare to NetBeans) for our. But is it possible to FORCE SET compiler, e.g. as I wrote c++98 or or native C without any C++? I mean by open qt project, not CMakeLists. How I remember CMakeLists + Qt Creator all was ok (I compiled C projects by CMakeLists + Qt Creator some time ago).

Comment: @jwernerny Yes, I'm sure since I have debug output in my pro file (`message("...")`) and it really reruns after each save. Otherwise I was not able to see my messages from my pro file. Also I run qmake manualy after each save in this case for sure since I see this reall delirium: I tell to qmake which compiler/language I want to use and qmake ignores my settings.

Comment: So correct answer is `CONFIG += strict_c++`. This was not resolve my second problem (`version CXXABI_1.3.8 not found`) since this problem from gcc version not gcc extension as I a mistake to believe but in any case answer is correct. Thank you @peppe. For select specific version of gcc/g++ the `QMAKE_CC` & `QMAKE_CXX` project directives must be used. E.g.: `QMAKE_CC = gcc-4.8` and `QMAKE_CXX = g++-4.8`. This resolves my second problem.

Comment: I need to disable c++11 too, but setting `CONFIG += strict_c++` in the project file, doesn't remove it. The makefile still contains `-std=c++11 -std=c++11` in the CXXFLAGS. Yes, I forced qmake to recreate it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Karl It is not possible because Qt header files require c++11.